# How do I generate regular expression from this deterministic finite state automaton?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-expressions

I want to create a regular expression from the following deterministic finite automaton:

*"abb" substring search*

[image: abb substring search]

How do I generate regexp from above dfa and what are the steps for doing so?

Deterministic finite automaton generated from snippet:

```
{ w in {a,b}* | w contains the substring abb }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [methods](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/) for finding a regular expressions for the language accepted by a finite automaton. In this case, though, you don't need them. If you have $\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid w\text{ contains }abb\}$, then any string in that language is just 
$$
<something>abb<something>
$$
and the regular expression for these strings is obviously 
$$
(a\cup b)^*abb(a\cup b)^*
$$ 
[or however you're used to writing regexps: $(a\mid b)^*abb(a\mid b)^*$, or $(a+ b)^*abb(a+ b)^*$].

Comment: What if we didn't have "contains abb" information? In the above example finite automaton, it is easily seen that it's substring search. But if we didn't see or know that. What methods should be then used? Or is the preferred way trying to first see what automaton does and then try to come up with an equivalent regexp?

Comment: @KlausHelenius. If all you have is the FA, then you could use one of the methods in the link I gave. FA-to-regexp is such a standard construction that it should be in almost any intro theory text.